# how to put the calendar icon of a datepicker inside a div or table

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to put the "calendar.png" icon of a datepicker inside a div, or even a table. The objective is to be able to position it wherever I want. With this I have managed to place it where I want:

```css
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  left: 260px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

but I wanted to put it in a div or a table. Only the calendar icon not the entire calendar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#demoDate').datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true
  });
});
```

```css
#container * {
  vertical-align: middle
}

body .fondo {
  /*: 100px;*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.widget {
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>jQuery UI Date Picker : buttonImage and buttonImageOnly </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="widget">
    <input id="demoDate" class="fondo" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Seems like using `.ui-datepicker-trigger` is the right way..

Comment: with .ui-datepicker-trigger move it to the desired place, but i cannot put it into a div.

Comment: Why do you need it to be in a `div`?

Comment: or into a table. It is because I have the whole page in a tabular form

Comment: Still I'm not sure how wrapping the trigger will make a difference but anyway, you can wrap it with [`wrap`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/). like this `$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').wrap('<div class="ui-datepicker-trigger-wrapper" />')`. demo: https://jsbin.com/vabidaz/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: and how can i put it into a table?

Comment: What table? basically you can move DOM element with `appendTo`.